# prometheus getting Integer count

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I need to show, in prometheus, a panel with the list of the pods that restart Value is greater than 5 for example.

If I have a Counter Value, How can I build a query to get a list with the names of the pods with the total number of restarts for each one during a period of time (for example:24hs)?

Comment: can you include the counter metric with the labels for reference

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
sum by (pod) (increase(<number-of-restarts-metric>[24h]))>5
```

Comment: this is what iam trying:
 kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="dxl-new",service="kube-state-metrics" }   and below are the  list (metrics) that i choose from, value is integer and it is the count of restars

Name, container,endpoint,instance,job,namespace,pod,prometheus,service,value


when i try the below

 kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace="dxl-new",service="kube-state-metrics",value > "2" } it gives me all values includes values < 2 also.